ST_Intersection behaviour
I have a linestring which traces part of it's path back over itself (a there and back trajectory). When I try to intersect this linestring with a polygon to try to get the distance travelled within the given polygon the intersects operation only keeps one leg of the duplicated part of the journey. Is there a way to keep both pieces of the trajectory to get an accurate measure of the distance travelled.
In terms of MRE I would like
select 
    ST_Length(ST_Intersection(
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-1 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, -1 1, -1 -1))'),
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 -1, 0 0, 1 0, 0 0, 0 1)')))

to give the result 4 rather than 3.
The only way i can seem to be able do this is to break the linestring into it's constituent segments and intersect each segment with the polygon. However this is taking a lot more compute time to complete as the trajectories can be quite long with many segments and there are ~10,000 polygons to intersect with.
I am actually doing this in Python using shapely but thought I would check with PostGIS first to see if this behaviour agreed with the OGC standard (and it does).

Interesting. That may well be a GEOS bug. You could try asking the project.

The result being a multilinestring, the internal segment order (or duplication) doesn't matter 1. For example, SELECT ST_Equals('MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 1),(1 1, 0 0),(0 0, 1 1))','LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1)'); is true. So while the intersection does not produce the result you would expect, it remains a valid result.

Regarding exploding the segments parts, you can do it inside an index so it is computed just once, and in fact it might become a faster operation overall.

Thanks @JGH i wasn't questioning the validity of the result as much as looking for a way to get the behaviour i want (which in the case of trajectories seems a natural one). It seems exploding the linestring into segments works fine as long as geopandas does the join (i assume with some spatial indexing) rather than doing a naive loop.

I managed to this efficiently in geopandas by doing the following
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import LineString, Polygon

line = LineString([[0, -2],[0, 0],[2, 0],[0, 0],[0, 2]])

polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[
    Polygon([[-1, -1], [-1, -3], [1, -3], [1, -1], [-1, -1]]),
    Polygon([[-1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [1, 1], [-1, 1]]),
    Polygon([[-1, 3], [-1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 3], [-1, 3]])
]).rename_geometry('polygon')
polygons['code'] = ['A', 'B', 'C']
polygons.set_index('code', inplace=True)

##################################################################

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(*line.xy)).rename_geometry('point')
points['next_point'] = points.shift(-1)['point']
segments = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = points['point'].shortest_line(points['next_point']).iloc[:-1:])

s = (segments
    .sjoin(polygons)
    .set_index('code')
    .intersection(polygons, align = True))

(s[s.notna()]
    .length
    .groupby(level=0).sum())

